# How does oc delete pod work?

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-pod

I would like to know what is happening when oc delete pod command is running. Want to know the steps like what happens before the grace period and after that. I know that the default grace-period is 30s, but sometimes doing this the timeout (I guess it is 500s) will happen and the pod does not get deleted.
Inorder to overcome this we use oc delete pod  --grace-period=0
So how does this it get deleted now while previously it was getting timed out?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to that appears to be very long :). Here is [very good explanation of the complete process](http://freecontent.manning.com/handling-client-requests-properly-with-kubernetes/).

The idea I got is that there are many components involved in it. Controllers, Kubelet, Kube-Proxy, etc, doing many things asynchronously.  So, thinking only about one part of the process (like a grace period) might not help achieve your goal.